# How to remove all duplicates that are in consecutive positions?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to be able to remove all duplicates if they are in a consecutive position in an array. For example, I have this array:

```
[1,2,2,3,2,5,1,1,6,1]
```

And now, I want to remove all the duplicates if they are in the same position. And in the end, after removing the elements, the final array will look like this:

```
[1,2,3,2,5,1,6,1]
```

And clearly, we can see that we are removing it if it is in its next position.

**Note:** I don't want this only with integers. I want to it work with all objects. Also, I don't want to remove all the duplicates. Remove them only if it is in the following position.

Ideally, I would like to do this in-place, rather than creating a new array.

So, how can I achieve this with [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1)

val result = list.filterIndexed { index, i -> 
  if (index > 0) i != list[index - 1] else true
  // or: if (index < list.size - 1) i != list[index + 1] else true
}

println(result)
```

Edit, for scalar types and data classes:

```
fun <T : Any> List<T>.filterConsecutiveDuplicates() =
  filterIndexed { index, i -> if (index < size - 1) i != this[index + 1] else true }

val list = listOf(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1)
val list2 = list.filterConsecutiveDuplicates()

data class O(val name: String)
val objects = listOf(O("A"), O("A"), O("B"), O("A"), O("B"), O("C"), O("C"), O("A"))
val objects2 = objects.filterConsecutiveDuplicates()
```

Answer (score 4):

You already have a java version, this would be the Kotlin one. We can take advantage of Kotlin's [zipWithNext](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html) to make it simpler, but to note is that we are creating a new list.

```
fun main() {
    val list = listOf(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1)
    val result = list.removeConsecutiveDuplicates()
    println(result)
}


fun <T> Collection<T>.removeConsecutiveDuplicates(): MutableList<T> {
    val result = mutableListOf<T>()
    this.zipWithNext { a, b -> if (a != b) result += a }
    return result
}
```

The print result is `[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6]`.

As DrPhill suggested, you can do it without an explicit second list, he did it with `mapNotNull`, but I would personally prefer it with `.filter`

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.removeConsecutiveDuplicates(): List<T> {
    return this.zipWithNext().filter { (a, b) -> a != b  }.map { it.first }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach!   It can be 'streamlined' a bit.  see my second answer

Comment: @DrPhill ah, yes, you are right, it can be done without the explicit secondary list, but I would go with `.filter()`. But I think yours is better, since my `.filter` does an extra iteration if I'm not mistaken, due to the `.map` to get the first element of the pair

Comment: It is just down to style - I would not fail any of these answers in code review, though theses days I prefer easy readable, clear and obvious code over other considerations.  Thanks to OP for interesting coding exercise....

Comment: And I much prefer your solution with filter - much clearer.  Excellent.

Comment: FWIW I don't think that .filter does an extra iteration.  I believe that the operations are performed sequentially on each member of a stream.  There is one iteration, and each member is treated to a sequence of operations (possibly even on different threads), with the results collected at the end.
Even if not, I am reasonably confident that the modern compilers/JITs will do a better job of creating fast code than I could here.  The increased clarity of this style of programming is worth far, far more to me than theoretical performance gains.

Comment: The print should be [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 6, 1] by the way

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Alex.T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72508803/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-if-it-is-a-consecutive-position/72508985#72508985):

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.removeConsecutiveDuplicates(): MutableList<T> {
     return this.zipWithNext().mapNotNull {a, b -> if (a != b) a else null }
}
```

[Edit: I now prefer Alex.T's modified version of my suggestion - it is much clearer.]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a Java method to do this:

I don't know of any method in Java that you can conveniently use to do this. Just implement the logic yourself. Try something like what's shown below:

```
int[] a = ... // whatever initial array value
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // final array after processing

b.add(a[0]);

for(int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i) if(a[i] != a[i-1]) b.add(a[i]);
```

`b` Should store the contents of what you want.

Comment: It works good with int. But, i want It to work with all subjects so this is not a good idea

Comment: Just replace int with other objects, then.

Comment: The logic should be similar

Comment: Here's a word: generics.  Go see what they're about.  This will only work with objects that implement equals and hashCode methods correctly.  Bad surprises if you don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
val list = listOf(1,2,2,3,2,5,1,1,6,1)
// if list is empty then result is empty list
val mutableList = mutableListOf(list.first())
list.forEach {
    if (it != mutableList.last()) {
        mutableList.add(it)
    }
}
println(mutableList.joinToString { it.toString() })
```